# converting between forms - symbols/subscripts - matrix products

Tags: matrix, formatting, vector, symbols

If I  have a vector of the form (xp+y, x+yp) do you have a simple way of creating the following matrix and vector from it: `{{p, 1}, {1, p}} * {x, y}`,  such that after multiplying the matrix with the vector, I get the original vector back.

If I have the following variables defined as such:

```
v1 = (a1 + 1) *(b1 + 1) *(c1 + 1)*(d1 + 1) *(e1 + 1)  -1

a1 = (x11*f11 + x21*f21 )

b1 = (x11*f12 + x21*f22 )

c1 = (x11*f13 + x21*f23 )

d1 = (x11*f14 + x21*f24)

e1 = (x11*f15 + x21*f25)
```

is there a fast way to convert all the numbers appearing next to letters for example 11 next to x in to subscript? My goal is to create a vector consisting of several elements that look like V1.

Comment: Ad 1): does your vector consist of two numbers and do you want to solve for x, y, and p? Or does your vector consist of variables x, y, and p as shown and do you want to perform a structural rearrangement?

Answer (score 1):

1) maybe something like that:

```
A = (Transpose@{# /. {x -> 1, y -> 0}, # /. {x -> 0, y -> 1}}) &[{x a11 + a12 y, a21 x + y a22} ]
```

where the brackets at the end contain the vector with the equations with the variables x and y that you want to write as a matrix.

2) When  doing computations, I experienced odd behavior when using subscripts as variables, but in principle you can use regular expressions and string replacement to get subscripts. (but I would rather use this only for text output like labels)

```
ToExpression@StringReplace["v2=(a11+1)*(b1+1)", RegularExpression["([a-z])([0-9]+)"] -> "Subscript[$1,$2]"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second part of your question this may be either a formatting issue or one of part extraction.  I'll address both.

For formatting alone you might use something like this:

```
v1 /. s_Symbol /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[s], _ ~~ NumberString] :> 
  Subscript @@ Characters @ SymbolName @ s
```

[image]

Note that the elements of the `Subscript` expression are strings.  For basic formatting this should not be a problem, but if it is you can use:

```
v1 /. s_Symbol /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[s], _ ~~ NumberString] :>
  (HoldForm @@@ ToHeldExpression /@ Subscript @@ Characters @ SymbolName @ s)
```

If you want not merely formatting but instead something like part extraction from a separate matrix `x` or `f` then you could use this:

```
x = {{q}, {r, s}};
f = {{w1, w2, w3, w4, w5}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}};

v1 /. s_Symbol /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[s], _ ~~ NumberString] :>
  (Part @@ Join @@ ToHeldExpression /@ Characters @ SymbolName @ s)
```

> -1 + (1 + q w1 + r x1) (1 + q w2 + r x2) (1 + q w3 + r x3) (1 + q w4 + r x4) (1 + q w5 + 
>       r x5)

The function `Part` could be replaced with another if you have a different transformation in mind.

Comment: HI Thank you for you help. I was hoping to create a vector whose elements are EXPAND[vi] (the first subscript of x would change accordingly). Once I have this vector I wanted to make a matrix of coefficients from all the xii and a vector from all the fii so when i multiply XF = V .

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the first question I would simply use Mathematica's Matrix Multiplication. This is done by using a dot.
For your example:

```
{{p, 1}, {1, p}}.{x, y}
```

yields to

```
{p x + y, x + p y}
```

Here is an attempt to solve also the opposite problem. First I form a 2x2 matrix by replacing the Plus.

```
matrix1 = List @@ # & /@ {p x + y, x + p y}
```

Then I look for elements which are a part of all the rows within a certain column.

```
vector = MapThread[(Intersection[{List @@ #1} // 
   Flatten, {List @@ #2} // Flatten]) &, matrix1] // Flatten
```

And the last thing I do is a divison of each row with the result vector and I as a solution I get the matrix.

```
(#/vector) & /@ matrix1
```

This is just a try I'm sure there is a better much more universal solution possible.

Comment: It is my understanding of the question that he wants to go the other way: start with `{p x + y, x + p y}` and get (held, presumably) `{{p, 1}, {1, p}}.{x, y}`

Comment: Mr. Wizard is correct!

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it. Posted a possibility also for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`CoefficientArrays[{xp+y,x+py},{x,y}]` yields the matrix.

Comment: I presume you mean something like `CoefficientArrays[{x p + y, x + p y}, {x, y}][[2]] // Normal` (`Normal` for presentation)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes. I should have suggested this as a comment for obtaining the desired matrix and the obviously there are no constant terms so the first element will be {} and Normal makes for display. I must admit to confusion about the question. It appears to be two questions and I remain uncertain as to the second question.